# What is best way to make a natural brown or red mailbox post if post is already spray painted Blue?

Tags: repainting

Mailbox Post is painted with Blue Spray paint.  Need to see what it would take to make Post a more natural brown or red Color.

Comment: two layer of paint

Comment: remove all of the old paint first

Comment: If by natural you mean "looks like wood", then you have to sand all the paint off and then stain it. But since it's just a post, I'd just replace it, rather than sand the old one.

Comment: @19565 I'm not sure "just replace it" is the easiest plan, if it's sunk into concrete. Sanding  and staining *is* probably the best choice here.

Comment: @DoktorJ Even in concrete 2 ft deep (unlikely), it still seems easier and faster to dig it up and bury a new one than hunch on the ground with a sander for two hours.

Comment: Plus, dirt mess will wash back into the lawn naturally. Paint sand with be there forever until you vacuum it.

Comment: Is this a wooden post or a metal one? Why can't you just paint it red or brown (or whatever color you want)?

Comment: Sanding with appropriate grit and an appropriate (e.g. orbital or belt) sander is unlikely to take 2 hours, but even if it did, that's a lot less time than breaking it out of concrete, buying a new post and concrete, mixing and pouring it, and disposing of the old. Probably by a whole order of magnitude.

Answer (score 9):

The same thing you would do if it was a wall in a house:

**Paint it white, or possibly gray, with primer to hide the old color, and then paint it whatever color you want.**

Comment: Red primer might be a good choice for either of those top colors, so long as it's a different shade than the red topcoat.

Comment: Paint it BLACK rather than white, unless you have some white lying around - you will get better coverage.

Answer (score 7):

### Paint it with enough coats to change the color.

All paint "prints through" when it only has 1 coat.  So the blue will print through and affect the brown.  That is normal.

If you want to pinch pennies, you can get some primer - its job is to put down a uniform surface.  Primer has vital roles in surface prep, but it's also a cheap way to add more opaque material.  You are better off tinting the primer to at least the lightness of your final coat, if not the hue and chroma (saturation).

However you can accomplish the same coverage benefit simply with more coats of topcoat, if you don't want to buy primer.

Answer (score 3):

> a more natural brown or red

Causes me to believe the post is wood, not metal. In that case, you could, if you choose, sand, scrape, or plane the blue paint off, leaving bare, natural colored wood.

Once you're down to bare wood, you may consider sealing it with a waterproofing coat, depending on what type of wood it is. Some woods are naturally water & rot resistant and need very minimal protection from the elements to last a long time, so this step is optional.

Unfortunately, we won't be able to help you determine what type of wood you have from a picture on the internet. Wood identification (from an online picture) is difficult enough that it's actually off topic at the [Woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/) sister site.

Comment: Reminds me of the meme "wood identification" "Yup, it's wood."